# Counting tags inside a iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, tags, counting

iframe src is like this:-`<iframe src="http://mysite.com/testing.php?id=7632762"></iframe>`
and the content is dynamic.How to find out number of `<div>` or `<li>` or `<p>` tags inside a iframe
by using javascript on server side or client side ?
-Thank you

Answer (score 5):

On the assumption that the iframe src is on the same domain as the source page and has finished loading its resource then you can use the following:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("div").length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("iframe>div").each(function(){counter++;})
```

Similarly for other elements. It would be easier if you add some id to the iframe.

Comment: Or just $("iframe>div").length

Comment: @Christoffer: that's easier, I admit.